# SQL Sum with multiple conditions and join

Tags: sql, join

I have a table like this below:

date, country, session

May I know how to sum up all the sessions based on the country and get the top 5 results?

The result will be something like this below:

Malaysia, 9000
Singapore, 8000
Brunei, 7000
Indonesia, 6000
Vietnam, 5000

Comment: Where are the _multiple conditions and join_

Comment: I am just assuming that it might need some conditions and join to achieve this. May I know how?

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(country) , country FROM sessions GROUP BY country`

Comment: I modified a bit, is it something like this can count the sessions based on country

select country, sum(sessions) as sessionsCount from `naimproperties_country_session` group by country

Comment: And add some `ORDER BY sessionsCount DESC LIMIT 0,5` at the end and you are done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT COUNT(country) as sessionsCount , country 
FROM sessions 
GROUP BY country 
ORDER BY sessionsCount DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

The [COUNT()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp) function returns the number of rows that matches a specified criterion.

The [ORDER BY](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp) keyword is used to sort the result-set in ascending or descending order.
To sort the records in descending order, use the **DESC** keyword.

The [LIMIT](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_limit.asp) clause is used to specify the number of records to return.